# Conway, continuity and homotopy

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\gamma$ be a closed smooth rectifiable curve in $G$ such that $\gamma$ is homotopic to a constant curve,$\gamma_o$ ;   furthermore let $ \Gamma(s,t): [0,1]\times[0,1] \to G $ be the function that satisfies the homotopic condition of $\gamma$ and $\gamma_o$.

Define $h(t) = n(\gamma_t;w) $ where $ \gamma_t(s) = \Gamma(s,t) $ for $ 0 \leq s,t \leq 1$ and $w$ is a fixed point in $ \mathbb{C}-G $. (Note: $n(\gamma;w)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ around $w$.)

SHOW THAT: $h(t)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ (Assume that $\gamma_t(s)$ is smooth rectifiable for each $t$. )

First of all, I can show that since $\Gamma$ is continuous and satisfies the homotopic condition, then for any $ \epsilon > 0$, there exist a $\delta >0$ such that $ |t-t_o|<\delta$ implies for all $ 0 \leq s \leq 1 $ $ |\Gamma(s,t)-\Gamma(s,t_o)| < \epsilon $.

Now to show continuity of $h(t)$ at $ T$, I need to bound

$$|h(t)-h(T)| = { 1 \over 2\pi}\bigg|\int_{\gamma_t}{1 \over z-w}dz- \int_{\gamma_T} {1 \over z-w} dz \bigg|$$
But how do I use the fact above to bound $ |h(t)-h(T)| $??? any hint would be great.

Comment: I suspect that to carry out a proof like this (without doing the 'ladder' construction) you might need something like  $ \gamma_t'(s)$ is uniformly bounded on the square?

Comment: @copper.hat thank you for your response, I'm sorry but what is the ladder construction?

Comment: See Conway, "Functions of one complex variable", Ch. IV, Theorem 6.7, in particular the parts marked 6.8, 6.9. It is a very nice construction.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, I'll check it out now.